# Was there a cartoon, possibly on USA network, that had cowboy-like men riding motorcycles in space?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Bon Jovi's "Wanted, Dead or Alive" I think of this cartoon.

Comment: Is there anything else you remember? This isn't much to go on. When was it broadcasted, what did it look like? Oh, and welcome to SF & Fantasy Stack Exchange.

Comment: And are you sure they were men and not mice?

Comment: It could be this: [The Adventures of the Galaxy Rangers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmDckVV5vxQ)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're conflating [Biker Mice from Mars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biker_Mice_from_Mars) with either [BraveStarr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BraveStarr) or [The Adventures of the Galaxy Rangers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_the_Galaxy_Rangers).